# getting infinite loop in c while using eof for specific value of input

Tags: c, eof

The following code in C accepts integers as long as data is fed into it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int x;
while(scanf("%d",&x)!=EOF)
{
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
getche ();
}
```

It works fine for integer inputs but on entering any character/float input it becomes an infinite loop.Why is it so ?

Comment: Why use `getche()` and not `getch()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) failes to parse any input, it will leave the input in the buffer and return `0`. As the erroneous input will never leave the buffer and you don't check for anything but `EOF` being returned, the loop will continue for ever.

Comment: A better check would be `while(scanf("%d",&x)==1)` which means "as long as 1 argument could be converted"

Answer (score 1):

on unix system you may send EOF with ctrl+d

infinite loop probably obtained because the function reads a character, sees that it is not a number and returns it back to the buffer from which again reads

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int c;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("%d %c\n", n, c);
    return 0;
}
```

if you put 'a', then you get "0 a" to stdout.

Comment: If the input entered was "a", then `scanf("%d", &n);` would fail to set `n`.  `printf("%d %c\n", n, c);` would print with an _uninitialized_ value for `n` - which may not be 0.  It is UB (undefined behavior) to print an uninitialized value.

Comment: yes, I wanted to show that the scanf() puts an invalid character back into the buffer

Comment: Thanks for the example demo, it certainly helped in clearing the concept!!